How to add Hilt dependencies on "libs.versions.toml" file in android studio
I am using Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1 Patch 1. Create sample project it default configured build.gradle.kts(app) in this gradle "libs.versions.toml" file created,
Now i add hilt on toml file after that, the file not showing in build.gradle. Attached screenshot please guide me to solve this build issue.
implementation(libs.hilt) showing error


Please don't post config file data as screenhsot

okay @Robert this is simple sample test file only, so that I shared it.

Hilt dependency in toml file with KSP
Add Hilt and KSP in toml file
 [libraries]
 hilt-android = { group = "com.google.dagger", name = "hilt-android" , 
                version.ref = "hiltVersion"}
 hilt-compiler = { group = "com.google.dagger", name = "hilt-compiler" , 
                version.ref = "hiltVersion"}

 
 [plugins]
 kotlinAndroidKsp = { id = "com.google.devtools.ksp", version.ref = 
                "kspVersion" }
 hiltAndroid = { id = "com.google.dagger.hilt.android", version.ref = 
                "hiltVersion" }

Add Plugin In Project build.gradle.kts
 alias(libs.plugins.hiltAndroid) apply false
 alias(libs.plugins.kotlinAndroidKsp) apply false

Add Plugin in app build.gradle.kts
 alias(libs.plugins.kotlinAndroidKsp)
 alias(libs.plugins.hiltAndroid)

Add hilt dependency in app build.gradle.kts
 implementation(libs.hilt.android)
 ksp(libs.hilt.compiler)

Now Sync gradle build and error will resolved
Happy coding :)

Thank you, It was working good expect ksp(libs.hilt.compiler). I changed to implementation(libs.hilt.compiler) after build successfully.

KSP is new compiler, previously i have used Kept

Hi @Atul
nav_version = "2.7.7"
androidx-navigation-compose = { group = "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose", name= "nav_version" }
how to add it on build.gradle(app) like  implementation(libs.androidx.)
I am not found any good resource so every time i struck with this please help me.

navigationComposeVersion="2.7.1".
[libraries]
navigation-compose = { group = "androidx.navigation", name = "navigation-compose" , version.ref = "navigationComposeVersion"}
In app build gradle
implementation(libs.navigation.compose)
Rebuild the project, that will work
Please read the blog post https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/dependency-managment-kotlin-android-version-catalog-atul-kumar-24cse/

The blog post was very useful, Thank you..! @Atul

**In toml file**
[libraries]
 hilt-android = { group = "com.google.dagger", name = "hilt-android" , 
                version.ref = "hiltVersion"}
 hilt-compiler = { group = "com.google.dagger", name = "hilt-compiler" , 
                version.ref = "hiltVersion"}

 
 [plugins]
 kotlinAndroidKsp = { id = "com.google.devtools.ksp", version.ref = 
                "kspVersion" }
 hiltAndroid = { id = "com.google.dagger.hilt.android", version.ref = 
                "hiltVersion" }

 **In app level plugin**

     plugins {
            kotlin("kapt")
            alias(libs.plugins.kotlinAndroidKsp)
            alias(libs.plugins.hiltAndroid)
        }

**In project level build.gradle**

plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.hiltAndroid) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinAndroidKsp) apply false
}

and in dependencies
dependencies {
    implementation((libs.hilt.android))
    kapt((libs.hilt.compiler))
}


Kindly Add some description about your answer, instead of  only code.
